# Многопоточность и обновление TableView

Tags: swift

Есть цикл по заполнению словаря, который я поместил в ansys очередь.
Как постоянно заполнять TableView новыми значениями из словаря?

Comment: Что значит постоянно? Сделайте сеттер для словаря, как только появилось новое значение он добавляет строку в таблицу. Но лучше после того как цикл закончился внутри вашей очереди вызвать 'DispatchQueue.main.async' и там обновить таблицу, просто нет смысла обновлять при каждом изменении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлогаю создать  массив который будете передавать в `TableViewDataSource`, затем заполнять этот массив в цикле, при выходе из цикла в  DispatchQueue.main.async{yourTableView.reloadData()} обновлять таблицу, а где вы заполняете таблицу данными передавать этот массив.

Например

```
var yourArray = [String]()
```

в цикле при парсинге делать  `yourArray.appent(yourString)`

затем обновляем т-цу `DispatchQueue.main.async{yourTableView.reloadData()}`

а в `TableViewDataSource` должно быть

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellll = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = yourArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @JasonMalvin всегда пожалуйста.